# Test Code Coverage Please help

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
@isTest
private class Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokersTest
{
    static testMethod void Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokersTestMethod()
    {
        test.starttest();
            Pricebook2 priceBook = TestDataInitiator.insertTestCustomPriceBook (); 
            Account acc = TestDataInitiator.insertTestPersonAccounts();
            Opportunity testOpportunityInsert = TestDataInitiator.insertIndividualTestOpportunity(acc.id , priceBook.id);
            vlocity_ins__Application__c testAppInsert = new vlocity_ins__Application__c();
            testAppInsert.last_name__c = 'testname';
            testAppInsert.Opportunity__c = testOpportunityInsert.id;
            testAppInsert.BrokerNPN__c = 'NPN1234';
           
             insert testAppInsert;
            
            List<RecordType> rtypes = [Select Name, Id From RecordType where isActive=true  AND (sObjectType='Account' OR sObjectType='Contact')];
            Map<String,String> accountRecordTypes = new Map<String,String>{};
            for(RecordType rt: rtypes)
            {
                accountRecordTypes.put(rt.Name,rt.Id); 
            }       
                
                Account act = new Account();
                act.Name = 'Test Account2';
                act.RecordTypeId = accountRecordTypes.get('Agency/Brokerage'); 
                act.Type = 'Agency';
                insert act; 
                
                Contact con = new Contact();
                con.RecordTypeId = accountRecordTypes.get('Producer');
                con.FirstName = 'Test User';
                con.LastName = 'Number One';
                con.Email = 'testing222111@sesaco.com';
                con.AccountId = act.Id;
                con.vlocity_ins__NPNNumber__c = 'NPN1234';
                insert con;  
                      
                User user1 = [select id ,Profile.Name from User where Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' AND isActive = true limit 1];   
                
            system.runAs(user1) 
            { 
               User firstBroker = Dell_DataUtil.InsertPartnerUser('BrokerFirstNameNew','BrokerLastNameNew', 'abc1111new@abc.com', 'testNew@test.com', 'brFN', con);
              
            }
             
            set<String> setBrokNPNs = new set<String>();
            setBrokNPNs.add('NPN1234');
            Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokers brokerAppShare = new Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokers(setBrokNPNs);
            Database.executeBatch(brokerAppShare);
            
        test.stoptest();
            
    } 
    }
```

My Main class is

```
global class Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokers implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    global Set<String> setBrokerNPNs;
    global Map<String,User> mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser;
    global String query;
    global Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokers(Set<String> setBrokNPNs){
        setBrokerNPNs = setBrokNPNs;
        query = 'Select id , OwnerId,BrokerNPN__c from vlocity_ins__Application__c where BrokerNPN__c in :setBrokerNPNs';
        
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        
        System.debug('****query'+query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> sObjList)
    {
        List<vlocity_ins__Application__c> lstApplications = new List<vlocity_ins__Application__c>();
        if(mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser==null)
        {
            mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser = new Map<String,User>();
            for(User usr : [Select id , Broker_NPN__c from User where Broker_NPN__c in :setBrokerNPNs])
                mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser.put(usr.Broker_NPN__c,usr);
        }
        for(Sobject sObj : sObjList)
        {
            vlocity_ins__Application__c application = (vlocity_ins__Application__c)sObj;
            if(mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser!=null && mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser.get(application.BrokerNPN__c) !=null && mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser.get(application.BrokerNPN__c).id != application.OwnerId )
            {
                application.OwnerId = mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser.get(application.BrokerNPN__c).id;
                lstApplications.add(application);
            }
        }
        if(lstApplications.size()>0)
            update lstApplications;
    } 
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
    
    }
}
```

*I am Not able to cover 3 lines

```
 application.OwnerId = mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser.get(application.BrokerNPN__c).id;
                lstApplications.add(application);
            }
        }
        if(lstApplications.size()>0)
            update lstApplications;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers with your code.

First, check your logic before doing unnecessary work. You checked if the map was null when it couldn't have been, you used an object when a simple Id would have sufficed, and you were checking for an empty DML operation before doing DML.

Second, some bad coding practices. Don't exclude `{}` just because they are optional when the for/if block is just one statement. Don't use a query string if you only need an inline query. Don't use database.stateful when it's not necessary.

Here's a fix for your code:

```
global class Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokers implements Database.Batchable<vlocity_ins__Application__c> {
    Set<String> setBrokerNPNs;
    Map<String,Id> mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser;
    global Batch_ShareApplicationsWithBrokers(Set<String> setBrokNPNs){
        setBrokerNPNs = setBrokNPNs;
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(User usr : [Select id , Broker_NPN__c from User where Broker_NPN__c in :setBrokerNPNs]) {
            mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser.put(usr.Broker_NPN__c,usr.Id);
        }
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select BrokerNPN__c from vlocity_ins__Application__c where BrokerNPN__c in :setBrokerNPNs]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<vlocity_ins__Application__c> sObjList) {
        vlocity_ins__Application__c[] lstApplications = new vlocity_ins__Application__c[0];
        for(vlocity_ins__Application__c app : sObjList) {
            Id newOwnerId = mspBrokerNPNVsBrokerUser.get(app.BrokerNPN__c);
            if(newOwnerId != null && newOwnerId != app.OwnerId) {
                app.OwnerId = newOwnerId;
                lstApplications.add(app);
            }
        }
        update lstApplications;
    } 
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
    
    }
}
```

Now, as far as the unit test, you just need to make sure the owner Id is different than the current running user. You have some utility classes here, so it's not clear that you're doing that.